# What is the best way to get sum of entries/values for each week for each month?

Tags: function, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet in Google Sheets with game price entries for various dates and I want to find the weekly total for each month in the dataset.

I have tried the following formula but I didn't get any outuput, nor a formula error.

```
= ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SUMIFS(month($D$2:$D$22);2;WEEKNUM($D$2:$D$22);$B$2:$B$22)))**
```

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample/demo spreadsheet for testing purposes?

Comment: I agree with Diego. Unless we have a link to the spreadsheet (or a copy of it), we don't have any data to use or test. So there is nowhere to start.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it does not exactly suit my needs. 

This is the spreadsheet : 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GApAiBWpdrRZNQI9U_UepHJbMxqQdIVlEYR9S_Rj4ZQ/edit#gid=0

The cells with the italic font are the ones that depict roughly the desired result for the selected cells. 

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. There's an error in assumption that each month contains 4 weeks. If you assume that a week belongs to certain month when monday belongs to this month, you can end up with 4 or 5 weeek long months.

Comment: Thank you for noting that. Yes, so I would like to edit my previous inquiry to also get the number of weeks for each month be them 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

I worked on it a little based on the table provided on your screenshot. I used a helper column to display week numbers using `=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(WEEKNUM(D2:D22)))`

And then used this formula and expanded it to match the rows based on Week Number `=sumproduct(--(WEEKNUM(D2:D22+0,1)=F2),B2:B22)` since `WEEKNUM` function is not designed to work with array values [image]

We are still waiting for a demo sheet if this does not work for you if in case there's any modification needed.

Answer (score 0):

We can show it using is all in one-cell-formula:

[image]

```
=query({A2:G\arrayformula(if(month(F2:F)=1;weeknum(F2:F)-weeknum(eomonth(F2:F;-1))+weeknum(date(year(today());12;31));weeknum(F2:F)-weeknum(eomonth(F2:F;-1))+1))\arrayformula(Text(F2:F;"MM"))\arrayformula(YEAR(F2:F))}; 
"select Col10, Col9, Col8, sum(Col2), avg(Col2), count(Col2) 
where Col1 is not null 
group by Col10, Col9, Col8
order by Col10 desc, Col9 desc, Col8 desc
label Col10 'Year', Col9 'Month', Col8 'Week of the Month', sum(Col2) 'Sum', avg(Col2) 'Average', count(Col2) 'Bought' 
format  sum(Col2) '#,##0.00 €', avg(Col2) '#,##0.00 €' ";0)
```

It takes columns A:G (1-7) and then adds a few more virtual columns that are later used by query:

Col8: Calculates week number in each month.

```
arrayformula(if(month(F2:F)=1;weeknum(F2:F)-weeknum(eomonth(F2:F;-1))+weeknum(date(year(today());12;31));weeknum(F2:F)-weeknum(eomonth(F2:F;-1))+1))
```

Col9: Extracts month from the date in F column and converts it into text that can be used by query,

arrayformula(Text(F2:F;"MM"))

It was very difficult for me get correct months in this query, so instead of using month(Col6) I converted orginal data and added new column.

The only problem is that id does not diplay weeks when sales were 0.

Comment: Oh man thank you for going into the trouble for this answer. It sure does not seem easy. I will test it soon and get back to you.